What's a Heine reference for the "Andréief-Heine identity"
The "Andréief identity" or "Andréief-Heine identity", which can be interpreted as a continuous analogue of the Cauchy-Binet formula, comes up a lot in the context of random matrix theory.   Gábor Szegő's Orthogonal Polynomials  cites Eduard Heine's 1878 Handbuch der Kugelfunctionen, p.288.  But I cannot spot the identity stated there.  Maybe it's implied by, or implicit in, Heine's discussion, or maybe Heine discusses this matter elsewhere.
Can anyone provide a better citation to Heine's discussion of this identity?
(Andréief published his work in the 1880s.)

Muir (vol 4) p.464, the great chronicler of determinant history, fully credits Andreief.
Szego's wording in terms of crediting is itself vague. "For B.2.10) and B.2.11) see, for example, Heine 3, vol. 1, p. 288." really suggests that there are other places to find it and it in fact doesn't necessarily say that Heine is the originator of the identity.
In terms of tracing the term I couldn't find any use of "Andreief-Heine" before 2010. References to Andrief go substantially older. An historically focused article of interest is:

Mitrinović, D. S., & Vasić, P. M. (1974). History, variations and
generalisations of the Čebyšev inequality and the question of some
priorities. Publikacije Elektrotehničkog fakulteta. Serija Matematika
i fizika, (461/497), 1-30.

which has no mention of Heine and gives full credit to Andreief. A text that links exposition by Szego and Andreief is:

Bellman, R., & Beckenbach, E. F. (1961). Inequalities. Berlin,
Germany: Springer-Verlag.

He explicitly states the Andrief identity and cites Andrief but also cites:

see Polya and Szego (Chap. 1),page 48. See also Andreief, De Bruijn,
Jacobson, MacDuffee, and Kolmogoroff.

Polya and Szego refers to to Vol 1 of "Aufgaben und Lehrsatze aus der Analysis" and it does state Andrief's identity there with a derivation. They cite neither Heine nor Andrief.
There seem to be a good number of citations pointing to Polya and Szego as source for the identity and given that it contains the result uncredited may be in part the source of the confusion of the origin of the result.
I checked De Bruijn and he writes: "The following wellknown formula" then cites Andreief.
The credit to Gram appears to have to do with the "square" form of the identity as it appears in Courant-Hilbert Vol 1 (using German 1924 edition) p.95 who write:

Einen anderen Beweis kann man der folgenden Darstellung der Gramschen Determinante entnehmen [..]


Another proof uses the following representation of the Gramian determinant [..] (my translation)

followed by Andreief's identity for the squared function. This likely is the source for that nomenclature in some Random Matrix Theory work due to Mehta who writes in his 1967 book when referring to Andreief's identity (p.70):

We then apply Gram's result (cf. Appendix A. 13) to write:

And in the appendix cites Courant and Hilbert Vol 1.
As a side note Karlin has called the Andreief "basic composition formula" see discussion here though I have found only one other citation adopting that coinage.
From what I have seen Andreief is the first to explicitly state the identity fully in the form as used today. It might be implied in Heine, but that doesn't take away from the identity having developed as such by Andreief. The terminology Andreief-Heine seems to be a modern phenomenon (I haven't found a citation earlier than 2010) and from what I have seen, even if Heine implies Andreief this wasn't widely understood and is not even explicitly claimed by Szego. So "Andreief Identity" seems wholly appropriate from what I see so far.
